# Android: Programmatically Setting width of Child View using Percentage

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I've read this article:

[Setting width of Child View using Percentage](http://andmobidev.blogspot.com/2010/01/setting-width-of-view-using-percentage.html)

So far it works great if we set the weight and width in XML but I want to do it programmatically. I've a table in my layout (XML) and I am adding rows to it programmatically. In each row, I am adding 2 Text Views. I tried doing like this:

```
TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.myTable);
for(int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++){
            NamedNodeMap np = nl.item(i).getAttributes();
                TableRow trDetails = new TableRow(this);
                trDetails.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                TextView tvInfo = new TextView(this);
                tvInfo.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                tvInfo.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                tvInfo.setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);
                tvInfo.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 10);

                tvInfo.setText("info");

                TextView tvDetails = new TextView(this);
                tvDetails.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                tvDetails.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                tvDetails.setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);
                tvDetails.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 10);
                tvDetails.setText(np.getNamedItem("d").getNodeValue());

                trDetails.addView(tvInfo, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.50f));
                trDetails.addView(tvDetails, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.50f));

                tl.addView(trDetails,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}
```

but with no luck, it shows blank screen but if I do it in XML then it shows perfectly. Please help me sorting out this issue where I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `TableRow.LayoutParams` and not `Linearlayout.LayoutParams`

```
trDetails.addView(tvInfo, new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.50));
trDetails.addView(tvDetails, new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.50));
```

Comment: Sorry, I didnt realized you talked about `TableRow.LayoutParams`, I thought it as `TableLayout.LayoutParams`. I tried with TableRow.LayoutParams and it worked. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Thanks but its strange, i was doing like this `TableRow.LayoutParams rowParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  rowParams.weight = 1; 
tvRank.setLayoutParams(rowParams);` but wasn't working. while your way did the trick.

Comment: **setLayoutParams (ViewGroup.LayoutParams params)** 
`Set the layout parameters associated with this view. These supply parameters to the parent of this view specifying how it should be arranged. There are many subclasses of ViewGroup.LayoutParams, and these correspond to the different subclasses of ViewGroup that are responsible for arranging their children.`